# Send a message and embed with 1 command (Discord.py)

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I'm trying to send an embedded photo to discord and send a message before it. I've tried several things but can't seem to grasp it.

```
if message.author == client.user:
    return
elif message.content.startswith('!brando'):
    embed = discord.Embed(title="", description="", color=0x32363c)
    embed.set_image(url="embed IMAGEURLHERE.PNG")
    await client.send_message(message.channel + embed=embed +"<@!368718923123456789>s photo!")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take another look at the [`Client.send_message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.send_message) documentation.  You need to give it the parameters `destination`, `content`, and `embed` separately, not added together.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    elif message.content.startswith('!brando'):
        embed = discord.Embed(title="", description="", color=0x32363c)
        embed.set_image(url="ImageUrl")
        await client.send_message(message.channel, "<@!368718923123456789>s photo!", embed=embed)
```

Comment: Thanks again Patrick. I need to do some more reading, I can grasp some of the concepts, others, not so much!